# How cq5 dispatcher will get to know when to flush cache?

Tags: dispatcher, aem

How CQ5 dispatcher will get to know when to flush cache? Can we know the internal process of how the CQ dispatcher will work for caching & load balancing?

Answer (score 1):

There is a replication agent named "Dispatcher flush agent", that (once configured/enabled) will invalidate the dispatcher cache when a page is activated.  Normally this will be activated from the author environment when a page is created/updated/deleted.  If you have user generated content this might need to be triggered from the publish instance also.

See [Invalidating Cached Pages](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/deploying/dispatcher/page_invalidate.html) for more details.

There is some information about the function of the dispatcher in general on the [Dispatcher](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/deploying/dispatcher.html#How Dispatcher returns Documents) page.

Answer (score 0):

> How CQ5 dispatcher get to know to flush cache?

As far as I know, the dispatcher creates one or more files with a content length of zero (or one) bytes. There is a listener who looks for files modification time. Did this change, the cache will be renewed.

> Can we know the internal process of how the CQ dispatcher will work for caching & load balancing

I don't think so. You can try it if you ask for deatails in Adobe's offcial developer forum.

If you want to start the flushing process manually, then you have to develop it. I did it for five months. Also, it exists a news group at Google. When I got the task, I found the way there.

Answer (score 0):

Dispatcher has all its configuration under dispatcher.any file.
The /statfile property identifies the file to use as the statfile. Dispatcher uses this file to register the time of the most recent content update. The statfile can be any file on the web server.

The statfile has no content. When content is updated, Dispatcher updates the timestamp. The default statfile is named .stat and is stored in the docroot. Dispatcher blocks access to the statfile.